# Get page http with update jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

In my `php` code, i get the web page with this code :

```
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'timeout' => 5
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents($url , false, $context);
```

It works, yet I have a problem. I wish I get the page with 1 or 2 seconds of delay. I receive the source code but the page will update with `jQuery`. It is not the same after.

For example the target page has a `div#result` which is filled by `jQuery` request after loading of page. For my part, I do get only the empty `div#result`.

Comment: Hi, you need ajax for this and .delay().

Comment: oh, impossible in php only ?

Comment: You can try using "sleep(2);" in php if that is the only thing you need

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's impossible, whether in php or jquery.